# cannot assign to array of pointers in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I need to keep an array of pointers in c++. I have a Set which keeps objects of my class. Then I need to iterate over the set and keep the pointer of each item in array. array is 2D by the way. so What I need in summary is :
pointers[1][4] = PinterToAnItem; the reason is I need to delete the item later, So I want to keep the pointer and directly go to that and delete it, instead of iterate again and find and then delete. But I have an error in assigning the array. I dont know how this idea will work, but so far it gives me error. Please let me know if it is not clear

**the error is : " a value of type *CONST* Movie cannot be assigned to type of Movie"**

```
struct Movie
        {
            int movieId;
            int shopId;
            int priceId;
    
        };
    
    Movie *pointers[100][100];
    
    set<Movie> setMovie;
    
    void main()
    {
    
    //reading and initialize the set with movies
    // for example movie1 = {0,10,3} so I want to keep in my array a pointer to this object as:
    // pointer [0][10] = ObjectPointer
    // I have error in loop body. Also (*id), id and &id does not work. 
                for (auto id = setMovie.begin(); id != setMovie.end(); id++)
                    pointers[(*id).movieId][(*id).shopId] = &(*id);
    
    }
```

2- by the way, do you guys think it is a fine Idea? can I delete pointer[0][10] which points to an object in my set? so by this way I don't need to iterate again through the set and delete (0,10). I have a pointer to (0,10) and I erase it from the set.
Thanks

***EDITED***

**The answer from @Jeffry is right but it does not work for rest of my problem which is erasing the specified item. i intended to keep a pointer to an item and then erase it directly. But we know set.erase(ITERATOR) or (actual_value). so pointer here does not work for me. I had to change array of iterators, then it works. So I completed here maybe works for some later.**

```
    set<Movie> ::iterator pointers[100][100];
    for (auto id = setMovie.begin(); id != setMovie.end(); id++)
                    pointers[(*id).movieId][(*id).shopId] = id; // I changed here as well
    setMovie[1].erase(pointers[1][0]); // works well 
// pointers[1][0] is an iterator to an item in set with movieid=1,shopid=0
```

Comment: Why do you need to manually delete the contents of `pointers` at all? `set<Movie>` will call all the `Movie` destructors when it gets destroyed, when the program ends.

Comment: Anyway, `set` has the requirement that its members are constant, to guarantee that once inserted it won't have to change the order later. The compiler is telling you that because `&(*id)` is a `const Movie*`, you can't assign it to a `Movie*`. If you absolutely insist on doing it this way--which, to be clear, you shouldn't, because it's a ton of effort and confusion that only seems to exist to allow you to try to double-delete things--you could change `Movie *pointers[100][100];` to `const Movie *pointers[100][100];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pointers[(*id).movieId][(*id).shopId] = &(*id);
```

tries to store in `pointers` a pointer to a `Movie`, pointing into the `setMovie`.

Now consider what happens, after you do this. What if you did:

```
pointers[42][43]->priceId = 44;
```

That would possibly invalidate the set (you could have twice the same Movie). That is why the `set` doesn't let you do it.

One way around is:

```
const Movie *pointers[100][100];
```

Then, you could store the pointer because you wouldn't legally be allowed to modify movies, and mess up the ordering. I'm not sure that makes it a good idea, but it would solve your immediate problem.

For 2, no, it would not be a good idea to call delete on a pointer pointing to a movie stored in your set. You did not call new on this object, so you should not delete it. If you try, you'll get a crash immediately, or much later.

Comment: Thanks but let me explain a bit. the problem solved by adding const. But There is erase function on set. So we can delete an item. maybe I need to use Heap, priority_queue. but I need to delete an item and maybe again add it. So i dont want to iterate every time to find it and delete it. that's my main trick and idea. if it works programmatically, it would be enough for me. But again I have to delete movie(0,10) and again add, add delete multiple times. I use Set or any LOG(N) data structure to for some searching functions which is not related to this problem but I have to. thanks again

Comment: Ok, that clarifies it, but don't use the `delete` word unless you mean `delete`. It has a very specific meaning in C++. If you plan on calling `set.erase` with a reference to the object you want to delete it might work. Still not saying it's a nice design, but I'm not saying it will crash, if you meant `erase` instead of `delete`